# scroll view in android

Tags: android, gridview

First sorry for my bad English,I am created XML file,how to scroll my image along with my grid view ,my grid view was scrolling fine but  my Image view not scrolling along with my grid view and when i am using MOTO g and nixes devices my images visible fine but when i am trying to show same as MOTO E small screen devices my grid view was not working

main activity

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
<ImageView 

    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="120sp"
    android:src="@drawable/spr"

     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />


<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_below="@+id/image"
      android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
     android:layout_margin="10dp"

    android:numColumns="2" />


 <ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="gone"/>



 </RelativeLayout>>
 </ScrollView>
```

Image activity

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/picture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="220sp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"

    />
```

Comment: use `220dp` instead of `220sp` at first for `ImageView` sections

Answer (score 0):

Set ImageView Height in "dp" instead of "sp".